# Why is GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT default 4?

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to upload RGB (no alpha channel) pixel data to the GPU using:

```
            GLInternalFormat = GL_RGB8;
            GLFormat = GL_RGB;
            GLType = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE;
```

Here's how my data is structured `u_int8* pixels`;

```
RGBRGBRGB -> row 1
RGBRGBRGB -> row 2
RGBRGBRGB -> row 3
```

The texture width is not a multiple of 4 for this particular texture.
I was able to make it work using `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);`
I understand now how GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT works. My question now is, why is not `1` the default in OpenGL (source: https://docs.gl/gl3/glPixelStore)

```
pname                          Initial value     Value range
GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT integer    4                 1, 2, 4, or 8
```

Is it safe to set it to 1? Otherwise, it'll break on textures that are not divisible by 4
**why is the default value 4?** Seems arbitrary...

Comment: Computer hardware shows better performance when processing data aligned to a machine word size (size of a pointer), which used to be 4 bytes for quite some time. It's not really about OpenGL, the same mechanism improves CPU processing too

Comment: Also note that originally, OpenGL only allowed power-of-two texture sizes, so the only valid texture widths where `GL_RGB` rows weren't automatically aligned at 4-byte boundaries were 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A texture or other image is a sizable chunk of memory that you want copied from CPU memory to GPU or vice versa. (Back in the early 1990s when OpenGL first appeared they were fixed function graphics accelerators, not truly general purpose.) Just like copying a block of memory to/from your disk drive or network card, the copy should run as fast as possible.

In the early 1990s there were many more types of CPU around than today. Most of the ones that might be running OpenGL were 32 bit, and 64 bit RISCs were appearing.

Many of the RISC systems, including those sold by SGI, could only read and write 32 bit/4 byte values that were aligned on a 4 byte boundary. The M680x0 family which were also popular for workstations needed 2 byte alignment. Only the Intel x86 could read 32 bits from any boundary, and they still ran faster if 32 bit values were 4 byte aligned.

(On a system with a DMA controller that could run in parallel with the CPU, it would most likely have the same alignment and performance requirements as the CPU itself.)

So defaulting to 4 byte alignment gave the best performance on the most systems. Specifying alignment 1 would have to drop down to reading/writing a byte at a time. Not necessarily 4x slower but slower on most.

These early 1990s systems also had enough RAM and disk space that going from 24 bits per pixel to 32 bits wasn't too bad. You can still find image file/memory format definitions that have 8 unused bits just to get 4 byte alignment with 24 bit RGB.